# Why does an empty dataframe fail an is.null() test?

Tags: r, null, dataframe, is-empty

please excuse me if my question is quite basic. 
 I created an empty data frame by `df <- data.frame()` and obviously the data frame is NULL (empty). when I try to check if the data frame is empty by `is.null(df)`, the result comes FALSE. Is there any difference between `NULL` and `empty` in R. In this case if the data frame is not `NULL` , then what is in the empty data frame and  when it will be `NULL`. Thanks

Comment: `df` exists, so it isn't null.  `is.empty(df)` is TRUE, though.

Comment: @cphlewis From where comes `is.empty`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I guess it's from `spatstat`!

Comment: @cphlewis. Error: could not find function "is.empty"

Comment: there no such function in R

Comment: It is `spatstat` package, as @cphlewis said above.

Comment: @AaghazHussain: you have to install spatstat package. Then the function is [spatstat::is.empty()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/is.empty) It's not a builtin function.

Comment: @cphlewis May I know when `is.null()` is going to be `TRUE`.

Comment: `is.null(NULL)` or `x <- NULL; is.null(x)`. As far as I know, there is no other use of `is.null()`.

Comment: @Pascal, My argument in case of data frame. Storing `NULL` and then checking will always lead to `TRUE`.

Comment: As soon as a variable is a data frame it can't be NULL because it has some contents: it has a class. The same is true for all other classes. For instance, in `a<-numeric()`, `a` is empty but not NULL.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`df` is not NULL because it is a data frame and thus has some defined properties. For instance, it has a class. And you can get the number of rows in the data frame using `nrow(df)`, even if the result should happen to be zero. Therefore, also the number of rows is well-defined.

As fas as I know, there is no `is.empty` command in base R. What you could do is, e.g., the following

```
is.data.frame(df) && nrow(df)==0
```

This will give TRUE for an empty data frame (that is, one with no rows) and false otherwise.

The reason for checking `is.data.frame` first is that `nrow` might cause an error, if it is applied to anything else than a data frame. Thanks to `&&`, `nrow(df)` will only be evaluated if `df` is a data frame.

Comment: You can check that `names(df)` is empty (`character(0)`), too.

Comment: its checking for rows of df by `nrow(df)==0` which is obviously of `0` and no need to write  ` is.data.frame(df)`

Comment: Depending on how you define empty you cannot just check `names(df)`. The following data frame `df<-data.frame(a=numeric(),b=numeric())` has not contents, but the names are nevertheless defined. So my definition would say it's empty, yours would say it's not. All a matter of what you acutally want to check, of course.

Comment: You need to check `is.data.frame` if you want to avoid strange behaviour in case that `df` is not a data frame. If you are sure that it will always be a data frame, then you can omit `is.data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame()` creates an object that has a *data frame* class. Because the object ***exists***, `is.null` will return *FALSE*. A `NULL` variable has no class and no contents.

Comment: `is.null` will return `FALSE` because the object isn't NULL; because the object *exists*, `is.null` won't return "Error: object not found."

Answer (score -2):

Above answers are correct, is.na and is.null couldn't not detect empty value in R. This is what I would do to calculate how many empty value you have in your data frame 'df' in this case.

is.na(df[df =='']) <- TRUE # this just replace NA to the empty value in df.

sum(is.na(df)) # would give you an idea how many empty values you have in your 'df'.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I don't think that's actually what the OP asked. I don't want to discourage you from answering questions on SO, but this answer (while it answers *someone's* question) is too far from the question to be useful ...