# R: if condition on empty data frame returns error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to extract values from a nested list of data frames. One data frame has a column which is data frame and sometimes it is empty. 
Therefore I used the `if` condition, as suggested in this post:
[Why does an empty dataframe fail an is.null() test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556658/why-does-an-empty-dataframe-fail-an-is-null-test) 
if (`is.data.frame(df) && nrow(df)==0`)

However, I get error as:

```
Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can someone teach me how to make an `if` condition to return TRUE/FALSE on whether a data frame is empty or not?

Thanks.

Comment: if(class(df)=="data.frame" & nrow(df)==0)

Comment: Post `dput` from an "empty dataframe". At the moment it's not clear what sort of structure you are building.

Comment: there is a function in R called is.na.data.frame()